# How do I convert this JSON to DataFrame?

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have a JSON that I am struggling to convert into a Python DataFrame. The JSON takes the following form:

```
{
    "chart_data": [
        {
            "date": 1639872000,
            "arrivals": 80,
            "departures": 79
        },
        {
            "date": 1639785600,
            "arrivals": 80,
            "departures": 78
        },
        {
            "date": 1639699200,
            "arrivals": 78,
            "departures": 77
        },
        {
            "date": 1639612800,
            "arrivals": 78,
            "departures": 77
        },
```

Ultimately, I want to achieve the following table:

| Date | Arrivals | Departures |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1639872000 | 80 | 79 |
| 1639785600 | 80 | 78 |

I have tried pd.read_json() but I always get an error "Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering."

Comment: A quick [googling](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore pd.DataFrame.from_records(...)

e.g.:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(data['chart_data'], columns=['date', 'arrivals', 'departures'])
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a dataframe in this way for your use case:

```
pd.DataFrame(x["chart_data"])
```

As the initial 'chart_data' object holds all the data you want the DataFrame to store.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you kindly for the tip. It worked like a charm.